# "Stack Overflow at line..." in IE

Tags: stack, stack-overflow

I'm getting the "Stack overflow at line:" error on IE. I've read a lot of posts here but since I'm not an expert on javascript I don't knot how to apply your solutions to my problem.

The part where I get the error is:

```
$(window).load(function() {
$('#slider').nivoSlider()
});
```

It is from a slider I'm using.

Any help is much apprediated.

Comment: You can't ask about stack overflows here.  It causes infinite recursion.  Next you'll be telling me that's Javascript on this very website that's causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This suggests something circular is going on: the load() function is invoked, which calls nivoSlider().  What does that function do?  Does it somehow result in load() being called again, which calls nivoSlider(), etc.?